# Making a function to get input from user with discord.py?

Tags: python, function, input, discord, discord.py

I wanna make a function in python that replicates the input() function using the discord.py module.
I have looked at the posts about using  `client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)`
but I don't know how to implement it.

Here is some pseudo-code I wrote.
Note: I have no idea what I'm doing XD.

```
def inputd(prompt):
 a = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
 return a
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards Mike

Comment: Basically... Yes I am kind of stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least 3 errors there:

1. You haven't defined `ctx`
2. `wait_for` is a coroutine, it should be awaited
3. The whole `inputd` function should be a coroutine as you're using the `await` keyword inside of it

```py
async def inputd(prompt, ctx):
    await ctx.send(prompt) # Sending the initial message

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    # Waiting for the message
    message = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    return message
```

To use it

```py
@client.command()
async def question(ctx):
    m = await inputd("1 + 1?", ctx)

    if m.content == "2":
        await ctx.send("good")
    else:
        await ctx.send("bad")
```

Comment: When you use this... Do you need the ctx thing?

Comment: Yes, you do. I think it's pretty clear if you take a look at the code...

Comment: When I try the function it sends 1+1 then I answer 2 and nothing happens

Comment: Are you sure? It works like a charm for me

Comment: could u send me the whole script of urs cus maybe my setup is wrong

Comment: ye but what setup?